# how to fix a texture reseting at the edge of curved shape

Tags: texturing

I am sorry if this is a simple fix but I am new to blender and have no idea what I am doing. I just modeled a curved shape for a project I am making and retextured it, but I dont know how to fix this problem of the texture not going around the sphere all the way. There is a ring around the whole model that isnt connected for some reason

Comment: Please edit your question with some pictures figuring the issue, and share the blend file if you can.

Comment: Use spherical mapping. Btw, did you use UVs?

Comment: I cant believe I forgot to add images! I am trying to upload one but I cant seem to be able to paste it into this text, and I cant find a way to upload the .jpg or blender file.                    I fumbled through a tutorial that didn't totally work and used shader editor to get where I am.

Comment: Lukasz-40sth I never knew that was a thing. I hoped it was bud could not find the name of this section of blender through my searches. I followed this article https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Blender_3D:_Noob_to_Pro/UV_Map_Basics and I was able to perfectly fix my problem. thank you so much to you both!